# understanding dconf and gdm magic

Tags: gsettings, gdm

I have difficulty understanding how `dconf` works. It consists of several profiles with several databases (user-db, system-db, file-db) but there is no mention of its priority.

What puzzled me is the following observation:

Putting *Greeter* settings into the local database (**/etc/dconf/db/local.d/default**):

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=1200
sleep-inactive-ac-type='blank'
```

The profile (**/etc/dconf/profile/user**):

```
user-db:user
system-db:local
```

This does not do anything, seems that *Greeter* ignores those. I can do `dconf dump /` and it lists my settings.

But when putting the same settings into a new *gdm* profile (/etc/dconf/profile/gdm):

```
user-db:user
system-db:gdm
file-db:/usr/share/gdm/greeter-dconf-defaults
```

the *Greeter* settings are honored. When I repeat `dconf dump /` there is no difference, regardless where I put these settings.

I was under the impression that all settings are merged, but obviously applications have the possibility to read from specific databases only. Or did I miss something?

I expected that all *dconf* settings are merged and that *gdm* reads them, regardless in which database they are stored. Otherwise I would expect `gsettings/dconf` to show from which database the setting comes from, but they don't.

thx!

Comment: I can only speculate, but seems that gdm really uses its own profile: https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/3.12/dconf-profiles.html.en Unfort. there is tremendous lack of documentation.